# django-mptt multiple trees and queryset

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

My model Class can contain multiple trees.

```
class MyClass(MPTTModel, AbstractClass):
    """
    """
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    ***
```

I suppose I could do:

```
nodes = MyClass.objects.filter(tree_id=1)
```

And using:

```
nodes.get_root(), nodes.get_children(), etc,
```

But I have

```
str: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_root'
```

Reading the DOC "Subclasses of MPTTModel have the following instance methods: ***"

How can I use the methods having multiple trees in one model class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `get_root()` and other methods on a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/). Instead, you need to call them on model instances. To get the instance by `id` use [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get):

```
node = MyClass.objects.get(tree_id=1)
node.get_root()
```

Or, if you are [filtering multiple objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters), loop over the resulting queryset:

```
nodes = MyClass.objects.filter(some_conditions)
for node in nodes:
    node.get_root()
```

Comment: First code is not working as u already wrote with: get() returned more than one MyClass -- it returned 168!',). 
Hence to get the root node I have to do root_node = MyClass.objects.filter(tree_id=1, level=0) and if I want to get all leaf myClass.objects.filter(lft=F('rght')-1). 
Right?